# Is it possible to write this as a linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

As per the title is it possible to write the following piece of code as a linq query.
in it current state i found it was not very performant taking about 1 to 2 seconds to complete on a few thousand rows.

```
var user = this.userService.Find<ApplicationUser>(userid);
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
List<ApplicationUser> allUsers = new List<ApplicationUser>();
foreach (var partner in user.Partners)
{
    foreach (var programme in partner.Programmes)
    {
        foreach (var tm in programme.TeamMembers)
        {
            if (!dict.ContainsKey(tm.ApplicationUserId))
            {
                dict.Add(tm.ApplicationUserId, new List<int> {partner.Id});
                allUsers.Add(tm.ApplicationUser);
            }
            else
            {
                dict[tm.ApplicationUserId].Add(partner.Id);
            }
        }
    }
}
var usersviewmodel = Mapper.Map<List<UserListViewModel>>(allUsers);
usersviewmodel.ForEach(x=> x.PartnerIds = dict[x.Id]);
```

i don't mind having to automap and add the ids later on but it would be great if this could also be done in the linq query.

Comment: I don´t think using LINQ would do any benefit here (at least in case of performance). If you really have to loop every ApplicationUSerID of every TeamMember of every Programmer there is not much you can do, using LINQ would just result in a shorter code, nothing more.

Comment: @HimBromBeere he is using EF so that is not true.  Converting the foreach iterations to LINQ allows EF to translate the query to the database's query language (probably SQL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
List<ApplicationUser> allUsers = new List<ApplicationUser>();
var groupedByApplicationUserId = from partner in user.Partners
                                 from programme in partner.Programs
                                 from tm in programme.TeamMembers
                                 select new { ApplicationUserId = tm.ApplicationUserId,
                                              PartnerId = partner.Id,
                                              ApplicationUser = tm.ApplicationUser,
                                             };
groupedByApplicationUserId.GroupBy(item => item.ApplicationUserId).ToList().ForEach(group =>
{
    dict.Add(group.Key, group.Select(item => item.PartnerId).ToList());
    allUsers.AddRange(group.Select(item => item.ApplicationUser));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only eliminate one inner cycle:

```
        foreach (var partner in user.Partners)
        {
            foreach (var tm in partner.Programmes.SelectMany(programme => programme.TeamMembers)) {
                if (!dict.ContainsKey(tm.ApplicationUserId))
                {
                    dict.Add(tm.ApplicationUserId, new List<int> { partner.Id });
                    allUsers.Add(tm.ApplicationUser);
                }
                else
                {
                    dict[tm.ApplicationUserId].Add(partner.Id);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

First go down to team members. Create pairs of `ApplicationUserId`s (as `TeamMembId`) and `PartnerId`s. When you have that group it by `TeamMemberId` and convert to a dictionary.

```
var userDict = user.Partners.SelectMany(
    p =>
        p.Programmes.SelectMany(
            prg =>
            prg.TeamMembers.Select(
                t => new { PartnerId = p.Id, TeamMembId = t.ApplicationUserId })))
         .GroupBy(r => r.TeamMembId)
         .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(i => i.PartnerId).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing seems to me like a simple GroupBy.

```
var query = 
    user.Partners
        .SelectMany(x=>x.Programmer)
        .SelectMany(x=>x.TeamMembers)
        .Select(x=> new { partner = partner.Id, applicationUser = tm.ApplicationUser })
        .GroupBy(x=>x.applicationUser)
        .Select(x=>new { x.applicationUser, partners = x.Select(y=>y.partner) }) ;
```

But I'm not sure if EF can translate this query properly. Especially the select after GroupBy.